# How to decrypt .dat file with (possibly) java code?

Tags: java, encryption, hashmap

I have a .dat file downloaded from a game, which appears to have some Java code or values in it, along with other illegible text. Here's some of the content:

[image]

My question is, is there any way I can decode this file? Or, how can I work out which encryption algorithm it uses so I can search more accurately on how to decrypt it?

Comment: That's almost certainly not encrypted, but it does look like Java serialization. You'll need a copy of the class that saved it.

Comment: It looks like a serialized `HashMap` to me. Just read it with `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`. There is certainly no encryption here, otherwise you woudn't be able to see that class name. But you won't be able to read it if the map contains objects of classes you don't have.

Comment: You will not need a copy of the class that saved it @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- You will need a copy of all the classes it *contains,* other than JDK classes, which may be none at all.

Comment: @user207421 I was sloppy; thanks for the correction.

Comment: @user207421 thank you, your solution worked! Please post your answer so i can mark it as correct :)

Comment: @user207421 i posted the answer below, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from @user207421 worked perfectly, i ended up using this code to get the file info:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("./file.dat");
            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            try {
                System.out.println(inputStream.readObject());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```